# add an element tag to an existing html

Tags: python

I have 200 HTML files that I would like to modify so that each <a element gets rel="nofollow", I wrote the follow for loop which gets part of it done

```
import os

for i in os.listdir('html'):
    with open("html/" + i, mode='r') as f:
        html = f.read()
        html_updated = html.replace("<a ", '<a rel=nofollow ')
    with open("modified/" + i, mode='w') as f_out:
        f_out.write(html_updated)
```

The problem I am having is that if the "a" tag already has a rel="something" it will not append it to it ideally it would become rel="something nofollow"

what is a good approach to do this?

Comment: That just means you have to implement a way more complex logic to handle everything you want. A simple replace is not enough.

Comment: Google BeautifulSoup which IMO is easiest to learn for HTML novices.